# Matrix Algebra: Find $v$ for $\|Ax\|_F\leq v \|x\|_F$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

Define real matrix $A_{n \times p}$ and $x_{p \times 1}$. $\| \cdot \|_F$ denote the frobenius norm.

$$\|Ax\|_F \leq v \|x\|_F$$

Can we find a $v$ such that the above inequality holds?

Comment: can you relate this to the Rayleigh quotient?

Comment: very interesting. Looks very relevant. Thanks!

Comment: Hints: use the [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition). If $U$ is an orthogonal matrix, what can you say about $\| U x \|_F$?

Comment: But U is cannot be orthogonal, I guess, because it is not squared.